# How can I create structs directly after each other in memory in c#?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I have a problem with C#. I´m trying to call following C++ method.

```
void SetPropertyInfoList(int count, ref AfwPropertyInfo propertyInfo);
```

I want to create a memory block with x AfwPropertInfo structs. I don´t know how to do it directly after each other in memory.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried using `AfwPropertyInfo[2]` to create an array of structs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you actually have there is an array. I expect that the C++ code looks like this:

```
void SetPropertyInfoList(int count, AfwPropertyInfo* propertyInfo);
```

Now, `AfwPropertyInfo*` does not fully specify what the parameter is. It could be a pointer to a single `AfwPropertyInfo` struct. Or it could be an array of `AfwPropertyInfo`. Clearly in this case it is the latter.

Change the p/invoke declaration to be like this:

```
[DllImport(...)]
static extern void SetPropertyInfoList(
    int count, 
    AfwPropertyInfo[] propertyInfo
);
```

Create an array of your structs:

```
AfwPropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = new AfwPropertyInfo[count];
```

And then initialise the members of the array before calling the unmanaged function:

```
SetPropertyInfoList(propertyInfo.Length, propertyInfo);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. My method belongs to an object. How does the method know to which object it belongs to?

Comment: You cannot p/invoke instance methods. Only non-member functions, or static functions.